# How to use continue in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to implement this piece of Python code in Clojure:

```
# Make sure the probability exceeds threshold*next best
for cat in probs:      
if cat==best: continue
  if probs[cat]*self.getthreshold(best)>probs[best]: return default
return best
```

How to use continue in Clojure. What mechanism should I use?

Comment: What is your current output and expected output? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: The functional style is different enough from the imperative style shown here, that you'd probably gain more by asking the question at a higher level. Most likely what you're trying to do won't need a loop at all, but some combination of `map` and `filter` and the like, in which case in the end there won't be any need for a `continue` equivalent.

Comment: The indentation doesn't look right in this Python snippet.  Shouldn't the second line be indented once more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(->> probs
     (remove (partial = best))
     (reduce (fn [best prob] strong text
                 (if (> (* prob (get-threshold best)) best)
                     (reduced default)
                     best)) best))
```

Most likely full of bugs, but the gist is 
Remove the ones where the probability is equal to best, then reduce the rest of them to `default`.

The trick to return early from a reduce is to use `reduced`